# Reducing to upper triangular form

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

I've just had some difficulty with this transforming this matrix into upper triangular form:
$$
\pmatrix{
i& 2i& -1\\1 & 1& i\\ 2-i& 1&  i
}
$$
I've tried almost everything. I've multiplied the second row by $i$ to try and eliminate the complex in the first column but no avail. I've also tried using the first row to eliminate the complex in the last row but that hasn't worked out yet either. I just don't know whether I'm even starting it out correctly or whether I've made some errors in my calculations.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\pmatrix{i&2i&-1\\1&1&i\\2-i&1&i}
\stackrel{(2):=(2)+i(1)}\sim
\pmatrix{i&2i&-1\\0&-1&0\\2-i&1&i}
\stackrel{(3):=(3)+(1+2i)(1)}\sim
\pmatrix{i&2i&-1\\0&-1&0\\0&2i-3&-1-i}
\stackrel{(3):=(3)+(2i-3)(2)}\sim
\pmatrix{i&2i&-1\\0&-1&0\\0&0&-1-i}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints to get you going:

- Add row 1 to row 3 to remove the imaginary part of $a_{31}$.
- Multiply row 1 by $-i$ to make the first entry $1$. (In general, if the first entry of a row is $a + bi$, you can multiply by $a - bi$ to get rid of the imaginary part.)
- Now subtract row 1 from row 2, and a multiple of row 1 from row 3, and you'll have cleared out the first column.
- Then try to do something similar for the second column, to clear out $a_{32}$, and you'll be done.